# slot size intuition question in 5G NR

Tags: ofdm

from the 5G NR manual shown bellow.
there is a diagram i have attache.
is there some intuitive explanation regarding why as the carrier spacing goes high then the slot time goes low.
how are these two connect together?
thanks.

https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_FrameStructure.html

Comment: Because (1) the number of symbols per slot is unchanged and (2) the higher subcarrier spacing, the shorter OFDM symbols: (1) is specified by the standard for scheduling purposes and (2) is the nature of OFDM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply how OFDM is defined: you take N samples, do a DFT, you get N subcarriers. Since the bandwidth is always the same, the subcarrier spacing is necessarily proportional to 1/N, and due to N samples taking time proportional to N, this subcarrier spacing · symbol duration is always the same.